# Question about Azure DevOps pipeline variables reference

Tags: azure, variables, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have two yaml file in Azure DevOps, I define a variables "AAA:123" in azure-pipelines.yml, and call test.yml, in test.yaml, I can echo $(AAA) with 123, but using "- ${{ if eq($(AAA), '123') }}:", I can't read the variables AAA, how should I write in {{ if eq() }}?

#### azure-pipelines.yml

```
variables:
  AAA: 123

steps:
- script: |
    echo 'start'
- template: test.yml
```

#### test.yml

```
steps:
    - script: |
        echo $(AAA)
    - ${{ if eq($(AAA), '123') }}:
        - script:|
            echo OK
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation (see [Understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)):

> Azure Pipelines supports three different ways to reference variables: macro, template expression, and runtime expression. Each syntax can be used for a different purpose and has some limitations.
>
> In a pipeline, template expression variables (`${{ variables.var }}`) get processed at compile time, before runtime starts. Macro syntax variables (`$(var)`) get processed during runtime before a task runs. Runtime expressions (`$[variables.var]`) also get processed during runtime but were designed for use with conditions and expressions. When you use a runtime expression, it must take up the entire right side of a definition.

Using a template expression should work in your case:

```yaml
steps:
- script: echo $(AAA)

- ${{ if eq(variables.AAA, 123) }}:
  - script: echo template expression
```

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate self-defined variables from main yaml in template, you can use condition instead of if expression.

**test.yml**

```
steps:
    - script: |
        echo $(AAA)    
    - script: echo condition expression
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.AAA, '123'))
```

[image]